# Difference between "deem" / "deem it" and "love" / "love it"?

Tags: meaning, difference, pronouns

Why do we put pronoun *it* there?

---

> We deem that she is honest.
>
> We deem it that she is honest.

---

> I love that he is honest.
>
> I love it that he is honest.

Comment: I would put "it" in the second, but not in the first. _Love_ definitely calls for an object, but _deem_ is much weaker, almost like "think" or "believe", which when followed by "that", do not call for (nor even go well with) "it".

Answer (score 1):

There is not a real difference here. Both sentences each time mean the same thing. *It* is often used as a provisional subject or object (object in this case) this way to perhaps improve readability.

It can also simply be used for matters of style.